# Simple jquery ajax issue

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery, trying to learn and written a following sample. This always returns error, what's the reason for this and how to fix this ?

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() 
            {
                $("#btnShow").click(function() 
               {
                    $.ajax(
                        {       
                            url: "www.google.com",

                            success: function(msg) {
                               alert("Success");
                            },                      
                            error: function (msg) {
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        });
                });
            });
```

Comment: Yes, tried but in vain

Comment: have you access to internet?

Comment: yes no issue with internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to do a cross domain ajax request.Browser will block the request because of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. You should either use `cors` or `jsonp` for cross domain request. For `cors`, required server should enable cors. In the case of `jsonp`, the required server should bind the response with a function in the client side.

Comment: well that is not an issue here....just go to console and make ajax to google it will send you right response to you

Comment: @Aaron no, it wont. you can check the console of this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/237/

Comment: Thanks for this. But I am bit lost. Can you please let me know how to fix this ? i.e. how to use cors any sample ?

Comment: In your above code, its not able to use either cors or jsonp. Because www.google.com doesnt support that.

Comment: you can use any of your local page for this purpose.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi its working in console you are sent but I hosted the same script in godaddy with a test page. But it results in error. I am unable to understand this behaviour. Ajax and javascript will be running from my browser, so it should not matter where my page is hosted isnt it ?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi it showing error like java script alert "error"